# wp_nav_menu() overrides ul attributes

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have built WP templates before but I used to build them from scratch and I didn't have any issues like this. This time I decided to use html5blank boilerplate. Now I have this issue in the `wp_nav_menu()` where WordPress overrides the attributes I try to add in the `items_wrap`:

```
    wp_nav_menu(
      array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
      )
    );
```

The WordPress docs state that the `items_wrap` should be assigned properly as `<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>`. There's also this filter function below that should supposedly replace the string values but there are no docs that I could find whatsoever that show an example of how do I approach it.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args($args = '')
{
    $args['container'] = false;
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing `item_wrap` completely from the array and assigning in the `menu_class` .

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I got it right – do you want the ul element contain the classes "nav" and "navbar-nav"? Then you only need to change "menu_class" within your array:

```
wp_nav_menu(
  array(
    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
    'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav'
  )
);
```

Comment: Yeah I know this, but it doesn't do that, instead it creates parent div with class name inside `menu_class`.